# Как работает строка кода? Лямбда, reduce

Tags: java

Вечер добрый.
Нашёл вот такую прекрасную строку

`String content = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)).reduce("",(a,b) -> a + "\n" + b);`

Знаю, что берёт файл по пути `fileName` и записывает его в строку включая переходы на новые. Но интересно, как работает сам код. 
`Files, Paths` - по сути же обновлённый старый класс `File`
`Files.lines` - хз (хочу знать) как, но считывает весь файл, через ctrl+click (пользуюсь IDEA) особо ничего не понял.

А ещё этот `reduce` - можно кратко что это такое и как работает?
Первый параметр вообще не понял, а во втором вроде как лямбда - выражение. В скобках параметры, стрелка указывает на функц. часть?
Если a и b - строки, которые объединяются, то каким образом и почему их 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `reduce` это операция [свертки](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0), маленький кусочек [функционального программирования](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) в java.

`reduce` это [функция высшего порядка](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0), она применяется к коллекции, принимает на вход 2 аргумента, первый - аккумулятор, это любой объект, в котором вы будете хранить результирующее значение, а второй - лямбда функция свертки, она применяется поочередно ко всем элементам стрима.

Лямбда функция свертки в качестве параметров принимает аккумулятор и один из элементов массива и возвращает аккумулятор.

Лямбда из Вашего примера конкатенирует аккумулятор и элемент массива последовательно, образуя единую строку, первоначально аккумулятор при этом содержал пустую строку.

1. На первой итерации аргументами лямбды были пустая строка и первая строка из массива, Вы их сконкатенировали и возвращаете из функции.
2. На второй итерации первым аргументом будет то, что вернула лямбда в пункте 1, те. аккумулятор, в котором лежит значение, второй аргумент - второй элемент сворачиваемой коллекции.
3. И так дале, пока не обойдет всю коллекцию

как то так